# Objective c: expected identifier error when comparing integers

Tags: objective-c

I just want to compare 2 integers, but I keep getting an expected identifier mistake. I thought this was a simple task, but now I'm not sure what is wrong. Here is my code. First I defined the integer. Ive tried both int and NSInteger

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger timeIntervalMinutes;
```

Then I just write an if loop to compare in AppDelegate just to test:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.timeIntervalMinutes = 5;

 if ([self.timeIntervalMinutes>10]){ //it gives expected identifier error here?
        NSLog(@"test");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Remove the square brackets (or the dot).

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry if this seems like a stupid question...

Comment: Not stupid but elementary. You should learn Objective C before using it. It is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use both square brackets (calling a getter method) and dot notation (accessing the getter as a property):

```
[self.timeIntervalMinutes]
```

Remove the square brackets.

```
self.timeIntervalMinutes
```

Or replace the dot by a space.

```
[self timeIntervalMinutes]
```

Comment: The code in the question is `[self.timeIntervalMinutes>10]`. Replacing the dot by a space `[self timeIntervalMinutes>10]` doesn't work.

Comment: @Willeke gosh yes, beyond what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets not required when comparing NSInteger in your code. Try below code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.timeIntervalMinutes = 5;

    if (self.timeIntervalMinutes > 10){
        NSLog(@"test");
    }

    return YES;
}
```